# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

first of all i know this is a relatively common error but it seems to have a different solution every time so I am posting in hopes of help. here is my javascript:

```
function showstuff(boxid, me, alternate, number){
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="visible";
    if (typeof number !== 'undefined') {
        document.getElementById(boxid).style.height="number"+"px";

    }
    else { document.getElementById(boxid).style.height="215px";
    }
    document.getElementById(me).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(alternate).style.display="inline";
}

function hidestuff(boxid, me, alternate){
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.height="0px";
    if (typeof alternate !== 'undefined') {
            document.getElementById(me).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(alternate).style.display="inline";
    }
}
```

and here is the html it's referencing:

```
<div><img onload="hidestuff('sched1'); hidestuff('sched2'); hidestuff('sched3');" src="/images/stories/calendar-ico.png" width="70px" border="0"/> Click on campus names to view schedules</div>

<img id='1reg' onclick="showstuff('sched1', '1reg', '1alt', 317);" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/olivetitle.jpg">
<img id='1alt' onclick="hidestuff('sched1', '1alt', '1reg';)" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/olivetitle.jpg">
<img id='sched1' width="389px" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/olivebody.jpg">

<img id='2reg' onclick="showstuff('sched2', '2reg', '2alt', 237);" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/libtitle.jpg">
<img id='2alt' onclick="hidestuff('sched2', '2alt', '2reg')" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/libtitle.jpg">
<img id='sched2' width="389px" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/libbody.jpg">

<img id='3reg' onclick="showstuff('sched3', '3reg', '3alt', 133);" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/centennialtitle.jpg">
<img id='3alt' onclick="hidestuff('sched3', '3alt', '3reg');" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/centennialbody.jpg">
<img onload="showstuff('sched1', '1reg', '1alt', 317)" id='sched3' width="389px" src="http://i.imgur.com/aBAtPM9.png">
```

I'm sure there is a more effective way to solve this problem in general but for various reasons I need to keep this method. My question is, why am I getting a syntax error?

thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an errant semi-colon:

```
<img id='1alt' onclick="hidestuff('sched1', '1alt', '1reg';)" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/olivetitle.jpg">
                                                         ^^^^
                                                         HERE
```

It's terminating your statement early before your closing parenthesis.

```
<img id='1alt' onclick="hidestuff('sched1', '1alt', '1reg')" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/olivetitle.jpg">
```

Comment: hey, i've fixed that so it goes like `<img id='1alt' onclick="hidestuff('sched1', ''1alt', '1reg');" width="389px" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="/images/docs/scheduleparts/markhameast/olivetitle.jpg">` but that still produces the exact same error

Comment: Now you have an errant quote: `''1alt'`. Take your time and proofread your code.

Comment: You also added a missing brace that may not have been accounted for by him?